# Do I need to change the literal paths if I am using url rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok so after many false attempt I was able to get hold of the redirects, now the CSS file was not getting the path, previously the path was

Directory Structure

```
<base>
   <stylesheets>
      default.css
   </stylesheets>
   home.php
   .htaccess file
</base>

localhost/my_website/stylesheets/default.css
```

And I used to write this as

```
<link href="stylesheets/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in `home.php`

But after url rewrite the path was lost in `home.php`, it was assuming the `stylesheet` folder is like

```
home/stylesheets/core.css
```

So I changed it manually to

```
<link href="../stylesheets/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And it worked, so does this mean I need to change each and every URL like this?

Also do I need to change the `header()` paths too? Right now they are like

```
header('Location: home.php?page=dashboard');
```

To

```
header('Location: home/?page=dashboard');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS styles disappear if I type an argument after index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272944/css-styles-disappear-if-i-type-an-argument-after-index-php)

Comment: @mario that's not only about the CSS, even my header redirects are not working so do I need to change the paths?

Comment: @mario any answers mario?

Comment: Don't put two unrelated questions in one. Also there are more duplicates to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute paths for your css and images.

```
/stylesheets/core.css
```

Or you could use [base html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag).

I am not sure about redirect paths though.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: home/dashboard/');
```

This can be used if you have made changes in the .htaccess for the values like

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

if you have the above code in your .htaccess then you can use the top suggested code.

Hope this helps