# Make .htaccess to keep REAL file path

Tags: .htaccess

Okay, I want my htaccess to rewrite `profile.html?id=1` into `profile/1/`, but all resources and scripts, which may be loaded from profile.html are requesting for `profile/1/js/...`.

Can I somehow keep real relative path of my file and prettify url at the meantime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS styles disappear if I type an argument after index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272944/css-styles-disappear-if-i-type-an-argument-after-index-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your files add `/` before the js, css, images etc. This should try get the files from the root folder.
So if you javascript file was in the `js` folder then it would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/script.js" />
```

Comment: You could try adding `<base href="http://www.example.com/" />` to the head tag in each page.